# C++ Getting Data out of Event Handler and Pass to Method of Another Class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, events, boost-asio

So, I've gotten myself into a bit of a bind. I'm making a sort of oscilloscope-esque program that is split up into a main class, a serial port handling class, and a class to handle the actual performance of the FFT. The Serial Handler class uses boost.Asio's asyncronous reading capability to read data from the serial port that I then want to passs to a member function of the FFT Handling class. The setup is pretty standard for the read. I've got an io_service object running on a separate thread that calls an event handler when there is data to read.

Therein lies the problem though. Somehow, I need to find a way to pass the data from the async_read_some's event handler, to a method of a separate class that also happens to be on another thread. I don't even know if that's possible to be totally honest. The two classes do exist in the main method together though, so I think it might be possible to pass the data between them. In the even that its not possible though, what would be a way to go about achieving the desired effect? I suppose worst case it might be possible to merge them into one class.

EDIT: here's some quick pseudo-ish code just to give a better idea of exactly how all this links together. Disclaimer: I'm not entirely sure how to properly write pseudo, I'm a bit of a bastardized programmer, so if it's not too understandable, let me know and I'll see what I can do to fix it:

```
//declared globally
boost::mutex mutex_;
sem_t qSem;
queue q;


class SerialHandler{
private:
    string portName;
public:
    void StartConnection(){

        //...some initialization things

        AsyncReadSome();

        //thread is initiated here
        t1 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
    }

    //the only important thing here is it reads into a buffer and calls the event after the read
    void AsyncReadSome(){
        serialPort->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(rawBuffer, SERIAL_PORT_READ_BUFF_SIZE),
        boost::bind(&SerialHandler::HandlePortOnReceive,
        this, placeholders::error,
        placeholders::bytes_transferred, q));
    }

    void HandlePortOnReceive( error_code &ec, size_t bytes_transferred, queue q){
        scoped_lock (mutex_); //from boost lib

        for (int i=0;i<bytes_transferred;i++){
            double d = (double) rawBuffer[i];  //pushes data into queue
            q.push(c);
            sem_post(&qSem);
        }
        AsyncReadSome(); //loops back on itself
    }
}


class FFTHandler{
private:
    double *in; //holds the input array
    fftw_complex *out;//holds out array

    int currentIndex;
public:
     void AppendIn(queue &q, sem_t &_qSem){
         while (1){
             sem_wait(&_qSem);
             double d = q.pop();
             in[currentIndex] = d;
             if (...){}//some logic to not overflow the in[]
         }
     }
}


int main(){
     FFTHandler fftHandler;
     SerialHandler serialHandler;

     //...some initialization of global variables goes here

     serialHandler.StartConnection();

     boost::thread *t2=new boost::thread(boost::bind(&FFTHandler.AppendIn, &fftHandler, &q, &qSem);

     char c = getchar();
     if (c){call stop functionality}

}
```

Comment: did you look at [boost signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/signals.html)?

Comment: @mvidelgauz I have never used boost::signals2 so you'll have to excuse my ignorance, but, judging by my read-through of the docs and the tutorials, I'm not entirely sure how I would be able to use this to pass data from the event handler to the the class on my main thread. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Sorry, at the moment don't have my code from old project. If by tomorrow evening no one will answer, I'll try to find code samples. Meanwhile you could also google for it (maybe with "site: stackoverflow.com" :-) ). I am sure there are plenty of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer:
I've never used boost::signals, so that might be the better solution. I took a quick gander at the link posted by mvidelgauz and it looks pretty good.

Here's how I would share data between the threads:
Have a global variable that contains the data that you need to share between threads. From what I can tell about your situation, I would use a FIFO of some kind. When the serial handler class event handler reads the data from the serial port and stores it in the shared FIFO (make sure you use a mutex when you access the shared variable), post to a semaphore. The method in the separate class in the separate thread should wait on that semaphore. When the serial handler thread posts to the semaphore, the separate thread will wake up and you will know that data can be read from the FIFO. Again, make sure you use a mutex before you read from the FIFO. Personally, I'm familiar with pthreads, so that's what I would use.

I'll do the best I can without knowing how your code works. Here's some pseudocode:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

// Global variable
Queue q;
pthread_mutex_t q_mutex;
sem_t q_sem;
// Make sure to initialize these variables somewhere

// Serial thread event handler:
char c = serial_port_read(); // I don't know how this works for you
pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mutex);
q.push(c);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mutex);
sem_post(&q_sem);
return;

// Separate thread that waits for this data
sem_wait(&q_sem);
pthread_mutex_lock(&q_mutex);
char c = q.pop();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&q_mutex);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I went ahead and tried your method (I included it above now), but I'm not entirely sure if I did so correctly. Is the semaphore informing the other thread that there is data to pop and then allows it to pop? I feel like I have not told my program when to call AppendIn() if at all. Would I include that in the main() maybe?

Comment: Yes, the semaphore is really just a signal. Waiting on the semaphore blocks the thread if the semaphore's value is 0. Posting to the semaphore just increments the semaphore; when that happens, the other thread wakes up, decrements the semaphore, and moves on. The call to AppendIn() should be in a while(1) loop so that it is always being called. This could be in main, but since it looks like main also needs to do other things, it should probably be its own thread. Also, I see you're locking a mutex once, but you're never unlocking it. Can you explain what you're doing with scoped_lock (mutex_);

Comment: I'm using the scoped_lock primarily for convenience because it acts as a lock only until the function goes out of scope and then automatically unlocks. Just in case some unforeseen error occurs and causes my function to return without unlocking the mutex. I'll update the question with the changes I make and I'll see if it works

Comment: Wow, that's pretty neat. Thanks for explaining. Good luck and let me know if you have any additional problems.